# MediaStreamTrack.onended not firing when selected external mic is removed on android chrome

Tags: javascript, mediastream

stream.getAudioTracks()[0].onended does not fire when an external mic is removed while being used.

Problem only occurs on Android chrome and does not occur in PC chrome.

Android version is 5.1
Tried on chrome v71+

On chrome v69, when external device is unplugged, Default mic onended event is fired instead of external device.

On chrome v71+ no onended event is fired on removal of external device.

oneded event is triggered when navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is called.

I need to notify the user that the external device currently being used has been removed.